# Seaborn factor plot hue requires no empty "cells"

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, seaborn

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1': ['a','a','a','b'],
                   'x2': ['c','d','c','d'],
                   'y': [3,8,15,25]})
```

I would like to see the relationship between x1,x2, and y on the same plot. I love seaborn's `factorplot` so I was thinking:

```
sns.factorplot('x1','y',hue='x2',data=df,kind='point')
```

Unfortunately, it seems that factorplot throws an error if there is an empty cell in `pd.crosstab(df.x1,df.x2)`.  In particular, the error is:

```
ValueError: low >= high
```

Not sure why `factorplot` would be unable to do this -- couldn't the empty intersection of `x1,x2` just not be plotted?

For now I'm using `row` instead of `hue` for `x2`, which splits the plot into rows. Is there a workaround to get the same behavior of `hue`? Is there something important that I don't understand about why this error happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed in the development version (i.e. `0.4.dev`), try installing that with `pip install git+git://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn.git#egg=seaborn`.